# How to make Firefox natively supporting SSL proxy

Tags: ssl, firefox, proxy

I'm currently setting up an PROXY SSL Infrastructure based on Squid Proxy and Firefox Browser, things that I can't change (not dependinig on me).

After several test i'm wondering those questions:
- Apparently, FF can't natively process SSL crypting; we can only specify in settings the way by which will through the flow already encrypted. Am I true or not? Is there any way to make FF crypt the flow in SSL?
- consequently, I had to use a proxy.pac file, based on a HTTP apache server (using TCP/80), in which in specified "return HTTPS $IP:$port". It seems to work, but honnestly I don't really understand why, in comparison with my 1st statement... Could you explain it to me
- Of course all certificate has been generated and correcly set into the browser

Thanks for you help
Kondor76

Comment: You question is kind of confusing and probably off-topic too. From my understanding you want to use a HTTP proxy over SSL using Firefox and you are complaining that this can only be done with a PAC file and you are asking how to do this "natively", i.e. without PAC, extensions like FoxyProxy or similar. Since the feature is not supported natively the only way to make it natively would then to change the source code of Firefox. But I don't actually understand what certificates have to be generated in the browser as you claim to do all this.

Comment: You understood very well what I meant! Greatfull The certificate I was talking about was the one I generated on The Proxy server et dispatched on all concerned client browsers...

Comment: The other things is that I still wonder if FF reallly can't do SSL encryption in that kind of case...  Is there a way or not? And if Yes, how?

Comment: Firefox can have an SSL connection to the proxy but you cannot configure this in the normal dialog. Instead you have to use either a PAC file or extensions like FoxyProxy. And for the certificate from the proxy: there is a normal HTTPS connection going on between browser and proxy which means that the certificate of the proxy gets validated as other certificates in HTTPS, i.e. must match hostname, must by signed by a trusted CA etc. There is nothing to distribute there.